# Certain expressions to validate json don't work

Tags: karate

I am trying to print the following:

```
* print response.requests[?(@.friendlyId == '#(ORID)')]

where ORID is:

 * def temp2 = response.teams[?(@.name == '<Name>')].requestedResources[0].resourceRequestFriendlyId
 * def ORID = temp2[0]
```

The expression is giving value as `null` where as if i use JSON evaluator, I am getting the correct json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only JavaScript is supported on the right-hand-side of the `print` keyword. And JsonPath is not supported.

I will update the documentation to make this clear.